# C++ Writing resources to disk

Tags: c++, writefile

*I don't know what i'm doing wrong.. the code is creating a empty file.*

**resource.h**

```
#define IDR_RCDATA1 101
```

**resource.rc**

```
IDR_RCDATA1 RCDATA "A.exe"
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "resource.h"
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {

HINSTANCE hInstance = GetModuleHandle(NULL);

HRSRC hResInfo = FindResource(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDR_RCDATA1), RT_RCDATA);
HGLOBAL hRes = LoadResource(hInstance, hResInfo);
LPVOID memRes = LockResource(hResInfo);
DWORD sizeRes = SizeofResource(hInstance, hResInfo);

HANDLE hFile = CreateFile("B.exe", GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, CREATE_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
DWORD dwWritten = 0;
WriteFile(hFile, memRes, sizeRes, &dwWritten, NULL);
CloseHandle(hFile);

}
```

Comment: You do zero error checking. Any of the function calls could fail, meaning that the ones after it also fail. For instance, if `FindResource` fails and returns an invalid value into `hResInfo`, then the subsequent call to `LoadResource` using it will fail, which causes `LockResource` to fail, which causes `SizeOfResource` to return zero, which means you try to write nothing to the file, which results in a zero-byte file. Stop assuming that everything worked, and check the return values of every single API call.